# How to open full size image when click on CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to open a full size image when I click on CardView. I have managed to open new activity but don't know how to show image in it

**NewsletterActivity.java**

```
public class NewsletterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<NewsletterAdapter> NewsletterAdapter1;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = 
"http://academypk.info/eleganceschool/jsonfiles/getnewsletter.php";
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "quarter";
String JSON_YEAR = "year";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "path";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

RequestQueue requestQueue ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newsletter);

    NewsletterAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);


    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();


}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        NewsletterAdapter NewsletterAdapter2 = new NewsletterAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);


NewsletterAdapter2.setImageTitleName(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

            NewsletterAdapter2.setYear(json.getString(JSON_YEAR));


NewsletterAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        NewsletterAdapter1.add(NewsletterAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new 
NewsletterRecyclerViewAdapter(NewsletterAdapter1, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
   }
}
```

**NewsletterAdaptor.java**

```
public class NewsletterAdapter {

public String ImageServerUrl;
public String ImageTitleName;
public String year;

public String getImageServerUrl() {
    return ImageServerUrl;
}

public void setImageServerUrl(String imageServerUrl) {
    this.ImageServerUrl = imageServerUrl;
}

public String getImageTitleName() {
    return ImageTitleName;
}

public void setImageTitleName(String ImageTitleName) {
    this.ImageTitleName = ImageTitleName;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

}
```

**NewsletterRecyclerViewAdaptor.java**

```
public class NewsletterRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsletterRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        Context context;

        List<NewsletterAdapter> getNewsletterAdapter;

        ImageLoader imageLoader1;

        public NewsletterRecyclerViewAdapter(List<NewsletterAdapter> 
        getNewsletterAdapter, Context context){

            super();
            this.getNewsletterAdapter = getNewsletterAdapter;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.newsletter_recyclerview_items, parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

            NewsletterAdapter getNewsletterAdapter1 =  getNewsletterAdapter.get(position);

            imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

            imageLoader1.get(getNewsletterAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                            Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                    )
            );

            Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getNewsletterAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

            Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getNewsletterAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

            Viewholder.YearView.setText(getNewsletterAdapter1.getYear());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return getNewsletterAdapter.size();
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
            public TextView YearView;
            public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

                super(itemView);

                ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;

                YearView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item1) ;

                networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


            }

        }
    }
```

**ServerImageParseAdaptor.java**

```
 public class ServerImageParseAdapter {

    public static ServerImageParseAdapter SIAdapter;

    public static Context context1;

    public RequestQueue requestQueue1;

    public ImageLoader Imageloader1;

    public Cache cache1 ;

    public Network networkOBJ ;

    LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

    private ServerImageParseAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context1 = context;

        this.requestQueue1 = RQ();

        Imageloader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {

                return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                LRUCACHE.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {

        return Imageloader1;
    }

    public static ServerImageParseAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {

        if (SIAdapter == null) {

            SIAdapter = new ServerImageParseAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
        }
        return SIAdapter;
    }

    public RequestQueue RQ() {

        if (requestQueue1 == null) {

            cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());

            networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

            requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);

            requestQueue1.start();
        }
        return requestQueue1;
    }
    }
```

**SecondPage.java**

```
public class SecondPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_page);
}
}
```

**Activity_Newsletter.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.techabyte.parentsapp.newsletter.NewsletterActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newsletterheading"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorHeadings"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Newsletter_recyclerview_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/quarter"
            android:id="@+id/textView_item"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/year"
            android:id="@+id/textView_item1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_item"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Secondpage.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use intent to pass url to other activity 
like this  paste belowe code where you click in cardview or in which click event your want go to other activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("url", your_image_usr);
    startActivity(i);
```

and recieve image url in your other activity like this means your imageview activity

```
Intent i =getIntent();
    String url = i.getStringExtra("url");
```

and open image using this [glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to show image

compile this in your gradle file file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

load image like this

```
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
 GlideApp
.with(this)
.load(url)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: @HarisDurrani check my updated ans and ask me in case of any query

Comment: Brother:  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", networkImageView);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   (it gives following error "Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView)'"

Comment: what problem happernd]

Comment: it says Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView)'... here is the itemview on click listener, where i click on cardview to open new activity

Comment: paste your code where you add this code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where i put it

```
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public TextView YearView;
        public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;

            YearView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item1) ;

            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", networkImageView);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
```